# Can' read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't understand why it gives me this error when , is this because i am using react router v6. Can someone look at this and tell if i missing something. Here is the code :

Code :

```
import { useParams, useMatch, Route, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const {id} = useParams();
const [book, setBook] = useState(null);
const match = useMatch();

<Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={`${match.path}/`}>
                <h4>{book && book.title}</h4>
                </Route>
             
            </Routes>
        </Router>
```

[image: error in console]

Comment: The [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-match) hook expects a path pattern string as an argument. It's not optional. It also potentially returns `null` so you'd want to use a guard clause/null-check on it anyway. What are you are trying to do with this code?

Comment: create a sub route for different sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-match) hook expects a path pattern string as an argument. It's not optional. It also potentially returns `null` so you'd want to use a guard clause/null-check on it anyway.

If you are trying to build descendent "relative" paths then you don't need to use the old v5 patterns of using the `match` object's `path` and `url` values to generate nested routes and links, RRDv6 routes and links do this automatically. This assumes the `Router` is rendered higher up the ReactTree than the component trying to access the routing context.

Example:

```
import { useParams, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { id } = useParams();
const [book, setBook] = useState(null);

<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/" // <-- renders on "/" relative to the current route pathname
    element={<h4>{book && book.title}</h4>}
  />
</Routes>
```

For example, if the parent component to the above component is rendered on `"/foobar/*"` then `<h4>{book && book.title}</h4>` is also rendered on `"/foobar"`. If there was a second descendent route on `"/barbar"` then *that* route's component would be rendered on path `"/foobar/barbar"`.